# AngularJS with WebRTC and Socket.IO scope issues

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angularjs-scope, webrtc, apply

I'm currently working on a video-conference call application with AngularJS, WebRTC and Socket.IO. I've stumbled upon an issue and am not sure how to fix it.

Basically I have a list of rooms which is looped through by an ngRepeat and then a directive is included. The html looks as following:

```
My rooms:
<div class="room" ng-repeat="room in userRooms">
    <div class="title">{{room.roomId}}</div>
    <div class="content">
        <conference-call></conference-call>
    </div>
</div>
```

The conference-call directive includes a template with the following html:

```
<!-- local stream -->
<div class="clients-wrapper" ng-repeat="client in room.clients | filter: getMyId()">
    <div class="client-wrapper">
        <video ng-src="{{localVideoURL}}" muted autoplay></video>
        <div  class="display-name">socket-id: {{client}} (local), stream-id: {{localStream.id}}</div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>




<!-- remote stream -->
<div class="clients-wrapper" ng-repeat="client in room.clients | filter: '!'+getMyId()">
    <div class="client-wrapper">
        <video ng-src="{{peerVideoURL}}" autoplay></video>
        <div  class="display-name">{{client}} (remote)</div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Populating the local video URL goes as follows:

```
function handleUserMedia(stream) {          
    scope.localStream = stream;
    scope.localVideoURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(stream));
    scope.$apply();
};
```

and for the remote video URL the following code is executed:

```
function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    scope.remoteStream = event.stream;
    scope.peerVideoURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(URL.createObjectURL(event.stream));
    scope.$apply();
};
```

In a later stage this will be replaced by something like `peerVideos.append(stream)`. But that's not what this is about. Because here's the problem:

> `pc.onaddstream` (the native WebRTC-function which is called when a
>   client joins) where `pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config,
>   pc_constraints);` is never called.

I think this is because of the following:
Whenever someone joins the room the server emits a call which on the client side results in a `$scope.$apply()` call (the AngularJS way to update and refresh the scope and re-render the page). This makes sure the client sees the remote client in the room he's in. However, because of this `$scope.$apply()` call the whole conference-room directive is refreshed and re-initialized. This causes the problem where `pc.onaddstream` is never called because no-one's ever added to the peer connection, because it is re-initialized, or at least I think this is what happens.

Has anyone of you had a similar problem? And how should I approach this issue?

Comment: `$scope.$apply()` updates the dom, wont affect the js values, but unless, you show the code for `pc = new ...` and `pc.onaddstream`, there is not much I can tell...